# Ruby on Rails Custom Generators with multiple sub generators

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

Hi I was trying to generate a custom generator, So my here my custom generators is `Myinitializer`, which has `myinitializer` inside it. But I wanted to have more generators inside it, like the `Rails` and `TestUnit` has. I went thought https://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html but i could not find how to create these sub generators or whatever they are called. I tried creating a new file inside the generated directory (`/lib/generator/myinitializer`) but it does not do the sub generator thing.

`rails -g`

```
Rails:
  application_record
  assets
  channel
  ...
  system_test
  task

ActiveRecord:
  active_record:application_record

Myinitializer:
  myinitializer


TestUnit:
  test_unit:channel
  test_unit:generator
  test_unit:mailbox
  test_unit:plugin
```

So what i wanted to have something like:

```
MyInitializer:
  myinitializer
  anothergeneratorhere
```

Comment: rails generators: https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/railties/lib/rails/generators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What rmlockerd explained only half answered my question, Here's what worked:

I created the custom generators using `rails g generator g1` and `rails g generator g2` and organized them into the following directory structure:

```sh
# directory: /lib/generators
λ tree
.
└── gorking_generators
    ├── g1
    │   ├── g1_generator.rb
    │   ├── templates
    │   └── USAGE
    └── g2
        ├── g2_generator.rb
        ├── templates
        └── USAGE
```

The content of the files are as follows:

```rb
# file: g1_generator.rb
module GorkingGenerators
  module Generators
    class G1Generator < Rails::Generators::NamedBase
      source_root File.expand_path('templates', __dir__)
    end
  end
end
# file: g2_generator.rb
module GorkingGenerators
  module Generators
    class G2Generator < Rails::Generators::NamedBase
      source_root File.expand_path('templates', __dir__)
    end
  end
end
```

After this, I am able to see the generators in place when using `rails g`:

```
GorkingGenerators:
  gorking_generators:g1
  gorking_generators:g2
```

I can then use them using:

```
rails g gorking_generators:g1
```

Comment: The only issue with this is that when using `rails destroy` it will not be deleting the correct generator as the path it maintains is something else.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your generators with a common module to get the namespace (sub-generator) effect you are after.

```rb
module Foo
  class Bar < Rails::Generators::Base
    ...
  end
end
```

will result in a generator called `foo:bar`.